# AWS boto3 how to get the metadata from the key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, metadata

I am trying to get the metadata value of the file uploaded in the s3 bucket

#i have to specifically use the boto3.resource('s3') for other api call in the project.

i have below data available under the metadata field

#metadata

```
Key=Content-Type
Value= application/json
```

below are the code

```
bucket= 'mybucket'
key='L1/input/file.json'
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3_resource.Object(bucket,key)
metadata = object.metadata
```

but iam getting below error

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be careful of your syntax. This line:

```py
s3_client=boto3.resource('s3')
```

is returning a `resource`, not a `client`.

Therefore, this line is failing:

```py
obj = s3_client.head_object(bucket,key)
```

because `head_object()` is not an operation that can be performed on a `resource`.

Instead, use:

```py
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3_resource.Object('bucket_name','key')
metadata = object.metadata
```

It will provide a Dictionary of the metadata.

Comment: Hi @John, appreciated for your answer .. however i am getting below error after replace with your code
~~~
ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
~~~ 
i have updated my question accordingly

Comment: That is an indication that you do not have the necessary permission to call `HeadObject`. How have you been granted access to the bucket? It will probably need to change.

Comment: i have below permission already set for the s3

 Action:
                  - s3:PutObject
                  - s3:GetObject
                  - s3:DeleteObject  
       so for reading 'metadata' specifically, which permission may required additionally?

Comment: Apparently you only need `GetObject` permission. From [HeadObject - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_HeadObject.html), it seems that the `Access Denied` error is because **the object does not exist**. (If you had `ListBucket` permissions, it would say `No such key`.)